# Multiprocessing Pool in Python doesn't use full CPU

Tags: python, csv, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using Python to process a large CSV file (over 10M lines), run a calculation operation on each line, and then save the result in a new CSV file. I tried to run the program in a Pool of 4 processes (the same number of CPU cores on my server), and it works fine for the first 15 minutes holding at 100%, but then it drops down to 60% for the reminder of execution.

The following chart shows the process. It runs roughly 70 minutes per input file, but it's only peaking to 100% CPU usage for 15 minutes. What can I do to speed this up and keep it at 100%?

[image]

The code is as follows. The resource heavy function is `doBigCalculation` (calculation and saving to another CSV), so I save 2000 of those requests in a list before sending them to the Pool for processing.

```
 p = Pool(cpu_count())

with open('input.csv', newline='') as inputFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    for row in reader:

        param1 = float(row[0])
        param2 = float(row[1])

        # This is the resource heavy task
        aqiRequest = AQIRequest(param1, param2)

        aqiRequests.append(aqiRequest)
        if(len(aqiRequests) % 2000 == 0):
            p.map(doBigCalculation, aqiRequests)
            aqiRequests = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Performance on a task like this is usually a little bit of trail, error and [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile). but first recommendation is to not chunk the the requests yourself. `map` has builtin chunking that will do this more efficiently, you can tune this with the `chunksize=`  parameter.
also using`imap` allows you to refactor the read into a generator, which in combo with  `imap` will lazily read the csv which should reduce the ram pressure from 70million rows.  refactored code as follows.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def aqi_request_generator():
    with open('input.csv', newline='') as inputFile:
        reader = csv.reader(inputFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

        for row in reader:

            param1 = float(row[0])
            param2 = float(row[1])

            # This is the resource heavy task
            yield AQIRequest(param1, param2)

def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

pool_size = cpu_count()
p = Pool(pool_size)
for result in p.imap(doBigCalculation,
                     aqi_request_generator(),
                     chunksize=compute_chunksize(10_000_000, pool_size)
                     ):
    # Do something with return value from doBugCalculation:
    ...
```

Additionally if there is some IO (you mention writing to an output csv) you might find that you get better performance by having more processes than CPUs as you might be spending a bunch of time blocked on writing the results.  (that might explain the spikes followed by the dips in CPU performance)

Comment: (1) You had an indentation error. (2) If you were using `map`, the *chunksize* value, if not specified, would be calculated to be (approximately) `*size_of_iterable*// (4 * pool_size)`, which is a reasonable starting point. So in this case, if there are 10M values being yielded, the I would use `10M//(4 * cpu_count())`. This computes to 625_000.  (3) `imap` returns an iterator that *must* be iterated to get the return values from the worker function. If you don't iterate it then you must use `pool.close(); pool.join()` to ensure you wait for all tasks to be submitted and completed.

Comment: (4) Probably best is to have the main process get all the returned values (new rows) and it creates and writes out the new CSV. If you try to have each pool process doing this it gets very complicated and probably would perform much worse. (5) Using the *chunksize* value as computed above could result in greater memory utilization than desirable and for that reason it may be necessary to reduce it, but 2000 seems too small.